# Равные пропорции нарисованного и вставленного изображения на различных разрешениях дисплеев

Tags: java, android, canvas

Здравствуйте.  Правильно ли я понимаю, что в практически любых играх и приложениях размеры нарисованного в canvas или изображения png jpeg загружаемые из ресурсов меняются в зависимости от разрешения и размера экрана.  В общем меняются пропорционально. А каким образом это достигается? Допустим если рисовать самому,  то можно через getWidth() например получать размеры и задавать размеры фигуры в долях от разрешения экрана. А как быть с загружаемыми картинками?  Как они подгоняются под все дисплеи? Svg  графику исключим, я ее и рисовать не могу и не пользуюсь пока что.